# How do I combine the total cost by a customer name in SQL query?

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

My Attempt is below:

```
SELECT BookLoan.borrowerName, Book.cost
FROM BookLoan
JOIN Book ON BookLoan.bookTitle = Book.title
JOIN Borrower ON BookLoan.borrowerName = Borrower.name;
```

I need to combine the total cost by the `borrowerName` but really unsure how?

Comment: MySQL 5.x or 8.x? It's easy in 8.x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT BookLoan.borrowerName, SUM(Book.cost) as TotalCost
FROM BookLoan
JOIN Book ON BookLoan.bookTitle = Book.title
JOIN Borrower ON BookLoan.borrowerName = Borrower.name
GROUP BY BookLoan.borrowerName
```

Comment: There should be a short description of your code for the long term good answer. A post in future is seen also by other than OP.

Comment: @badcoder11 you're welcome, please accept my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Group by & Sum.

```
SELECT BookLoan.borrowerName
, SUM(Book.cost) AS TotalCost
FROM BookLoan 
LEFT JOIN Book 
  ON Book.title = BookLoan.bookTitle
LEFT JOIN Borrower 
  ON Borrower.name = BookLoan.borrowerName
GROUP BY BookLoan.borrowerName
ORDER BY BookLoan.borrowerName;
```